# Extract Android application icon using aapt

Tags: android, xml, icons, aapt

I need to extract the application icon in a APK file.
I'm using aapt to know the icon location inside the APK file.
I'm running **aapt dump badging com.example.app.apk**:
this command returns me:

```
(...)
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
application-icon-480:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
application-icon-640:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
application-icon-65534:'res/drawable-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
(...)
```

but as you can see it returns me the location of an XML file which in some way is encrypted. I know this XML file has the real path for the PNG file icon, but I don't know how can I get that real path (or how can I decrypt the XML and then parse it).

Is there any way to get the real path for an application icon inside a APK file with a XML pointing to other location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this project,

> https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool

It can be used to unarchive an APK, including the assets.

```
apktool d <your>.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

try extract  your apk file with 7-zip and you will get res foulder

Answer (score 0):

Run this small script in a folder with your apk and it will extract the icon for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
APK_FILE="$(find . -name *.apk)"
eval ICON_PATH="$(aapt d --values badging "${APK_FILE}" | grep "application:" | awk -F "icon=" '{print $2}')"
unzip -j "$APK_FILE" $ICON_PATH
```